# How can I fix the error in the code below?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I could not solve the error in the code below. The files in the dir_sp_train and dir_sp_test folders are all in png format. While some spirals are colored, some are black and white, could this be the reason for the error?

**CODE:**

```
dataset_sp=[]
count=0
for file in os.listdir(dir_sp_train):
    path=os.path.join(dir_sp_train,file)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        for im in os.listdir(path):
            image=load_img(os.path.join(path,im), grayscale=False, color_mode='rgb', target_size=(100,100))
            image=img_to_array(image)
            image=image/255.0
            dataset_sp.append([image,count])
        count=count+1

testset_sp=[]
count=0
for file in os.listdir(dir_sp_test):
    path=os.path.join(dir_sp_test,file)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        for im in os.listdir(path):
            image=load_img(os.path.join(path,im), grayscale=False, color_mode='rgb', target_size=(100,100))
            image=img_to_array(image)
            image=image/255.0
            testset_sp.append([image,count])
        count=count+1
```

**ERROR**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-2c5acbe01962> in <cell line: 15>()
     17     if os.path.isdir(path):
     18         for im in os.listdir(path):
---> 19             image=load_img(os.path.join(path,im), grayscale=False, color_mode='rgb', target_size=(100,100))
     20             image=img_to_array(image)
     21             image=image/255.0

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3028     for message in accept_warnings:
   3029         warnings.warn(message)
-> 3030     raise UnidentifiedImageError(
   3031         "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   3032     )

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f481429bb80>
```

Comment: Maybe `print(os.path.join(path,im))` in between 18 and 19 might help. Perhaps you have an unexpected file or folder in that location.